# Is it good user experience to only require an email address at signup?

Tags: registration, password

Is it a good idea to only require an email address from users at signup (without a password or other details)? After they sign up, we will send a random password to their email address; this password can be customised after the user logs in.

Are there any possible downsides to doing this?

Comment: If you were to take this approach I would recommend that you get the user to change the password immediately to something more memorable.

Comment: @CaptainSpectacular This is not forcing but optional right ?  some user might be lazy and just prefer copy/paste from their email.

Comment: [your recent question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19751/should-we-send-both-username-and-password-after-registration) asked about sending passwords in email, to which it was shown this is **a bad idea**. Are you still considering sending passwords via email?

Comment: @JonW this is different, this is the random generated password, not the password that user set by themselves. For the password user set by themselve there is a possibility that they use that password in others website too. That is a security threat.

Comment: @SarawutPositwinyu I wouldn't force it, just recommend it.

Comment: @SarawutPositwinyu sending *any* password in plain-text, regardless of whether it will be changed or not later is a bad idea.

Comment: @JonW What is an example of sending a random password can be bad ? It is just like someone hack in a user email and signup by himself anyway.

Comment: @SarawutPositwinyu because you're basically just announcing to the recipient that passwords are stored in plain-text format for your site (whether they actually are or not). It gives the appearance of non-security.

Comment: If you're sending a plain text password in email, it should *certainly* be one-use-only with a "forced" password change...it's not really a password change but rather *setting* the password. But generally I'd suggest the same as @JonW, don't send it, use a link.

Comment: @SarawutPositwinyu it does not require email to be cracked by an attacker.  Email is copied across a(several) network(s), with multiple machines handling it by its very nature.  You might as well be mailing it to them in a clear envelope.

Comment: @BenBrocka so you are okay with a random person _setting_ the password for your accounts?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake If you're not using HTTPS for your mail and/or other people have access to your account you have bigger problems...a temporary link *only* to set your password seems acceptable, you have to trust their email to *some* extent and the password is not stored in plain text.

Comment: @BenBrocka That only covers the connection between you and your provider. Do you know that the intervening hops are not holding a copy of your message? If you don't want it read, don't send it plaintext.

Comment: @SarawutPositwinyu - you shouldn't be storing users' passwords in the first place. You should be storing salted hashes, only.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye i store in salted hash already.

Comment: @SarawutPositwinyu - how are you sending users' passwords, then? Are you only sending the passwords before the hashing stage?

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye exactly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Emailing the password exposes it, since it is sent as unencrypted text.

- If you do email the password, make sure the user changes it during the first login.
- **Alternatively, you could send a link to a continue page where the user can choose a password.** This link has to have a time limit, since the link is also sent as unencrypted text.

  You can use the same technique for resetting the password if the user forgets it.

Even **if you do ask the user for a password during signup (this is the most secure out of the two options)**, sending an email for confirming the email address prior to enabling the account is a good idea (prevents others from signing up using your email address).
This email should have a deadline (e.g. an hour or one day), so that the account will be cancelled if the email address is not confirmed. This will also enable signing up with the same user name but using the correct email address after the timeout.

Also, you may want to consider letting the user fill additional fields e.g. a display name or user name either before sending the email or after the email has been received.

Comment: I don't agree. There are a few types of web-apps that requre such level of secury like banking systems etc. Who whould hijack emails for a dating site or a harmless blog? IMO usability (like generating password automatically and asking less data during registration) is more important.

Comment: @ADO: The people from 4chan do this all the time for fun, and post fairly believable stories impersonating the user, such as saying that they are leaving their wives because they are gay, or - always impersonating the user - posting child porn pictures and then saying "whoops I posted the wrong picture how do I delete this??", etc. This can be very harmful to a person's reputation. Keeping blogs, dating websites, facebook and the like secure is of *extreme importance*.

Comment: +200 for the security comments, plain text passwords are **always** the wrong choice. -1 for email verification since we are talking about _user experience_ and email verification always adds to the length of the registration process.  Additionally, for me, it feels like they want to be able to spam me later making me more likely to not sign up or use a fake email address; yes I can give a fake email address and still _verify_ it.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake I keep getting emails from various sites that others signed up to using my address. I would gladly verify my email every time to prevent this. If the site asks for my email, it should verify it, if not then it shouldn't.

Comment: @ADOConnection you don't need to hijack an email account to read emails. Unless the sender and every email server the mail goes through use a secure connection, a man in the middle attack can be used to listen to emails going through the web. See this link for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_privacy

Comment: @DannyVarod Over fifteen years, across three academic accounts; yahoo, hotmail, and gmail accounts; in addition to seven employer accounts, I have never seen anything attributable to being signed up in such a fashion.  I acknowledge the possibility, but there are much simpler and effective ways of spamming people.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake NO! simple example: we have a local mountain bike club, and we counduct some races during summer. I've made a simple online registration app where you have an account and can register to races. You can only register/unregister and enter name. No one cares if someone's identity will be stolen: nothing will happen. You just come to race and if you'r not in list - register again.

Comment: @DannyVarod, I care about security a lot. Your example is bad for a following reason: If someone can read my email  the war is already lost. As attaker, I can start password recovery process, read password recovery link form my victim's email and im done. So hiding password from mail won't add extra securitiy. Unless someone have acess to your PC/Email account. But in this case I'd rather worry about my paypal account, corporate KBs with where live servers data is stored etc..

Comment: @AndreasBonini, nothing will stop me from registring on facebook with newly registered email like randomEmailG72Fzs@gmail.com, set name to "Andreas Bonini" and post whatever I like. it doesn't matter how password will be delivered. Since email is actually hidden, no one will be able to validate identity.

Comment: @ADOConnection email is **not** "actually hidden".  See [Password sent via email upon registration](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13983/password-sent-via-email-upon-registration) on Security Stackexchange.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake excuse me, can you be a bit more clear. I can't get your point. What im trying to say is that ussualy email is not displayed, So if someone will register on facebook with same name as mine, my friends won't be able to determine wich account is fake. Is that clear? Of course its more secure not to send password, use two stage verification using mobile phone maybe. **But you have to understand what kind of data you protecting** if data is not critical, there is no need in complex security processes! Can you provide real life example to confirm im not right?

Comment: @ADOConnection I was merely stating that email unprotected by encryption or an end-to-end secure channel is insecure. I see that your point to Andreas addresses a different concern.  Re: understanding the data you are protecting - In your mountain bike example, having only names on a list, I think that no password should be required. Also note my disagreement with email verification. But the OP laid out a plan to **"send a random password to their email address"** and therefore needs to understand that they are protecting a password and implying some minimum level of security.

Comment: @ADOConnection I have been using email accounts since the days of Netscape Navigator 2. I often get emails sent to the wrong person delivered to my addresses with the shorter names from a variety of sites e.g. school parent boards, travelling sites, dating sites and various other sites. If you have an email address named adoconn@gmail.com and adoconnect@yahoo.com and you don't have a good memory, there is a high chance you will mix the two up and sign up with adoconnect@gmail.com or adoconn@yahoo.com.

Comment: @ADOConnection As of email security, check out wikileaks. The attackers may not be able to read emails whenever they please, but they can record packages going through various servers and even attempt to reroute packages through their server, by transmitting false distance measurement packages. They may not get all your emails or complete emails (even though that could happen too), but the fragments may be useful. That is why I recommended time-outs (preferably short) on reset links.

Comment: @ADOConnection - you're assuming that users will use different passwords for high and low security services, so that one password being stolen won't provide access to other services. That's a dangerous assumption.

Comment: Im sorry, Im bored to argue. Here is example: http://www.serverdensity.com/ monitoring service, they send password in email when you register, so according to your comments "those loosers have security issue"? Im not sure. Great and friendly site.

Comment: @ADOConnection If you don't believe us, ask in http://security.stackexchange.com/ since this is a security issue and not just a UX issue.

Answer (score 6):

Anything that reduces the friction in the sign up process is a good idea. If the user is presented with a form that requires more than a couple of seconds to fill in they're more likely to abandon the process. Only having one field to fill in is the ideal form in that respect.

Of course, the really important thing is it have something that the user wants to sign up *for*. Don't require sign up just to enter the site. That would guarantee that a lot of people won't bother.

As @Captain Spectacular points out make sure that the first thing they do when they do confirm their e-mail address/sign in is change the password. Otherwise they'd carry on using the generated password which *might* be a security issue (depending on how you generate and store the passwords).

If you can send a link to the "confirm e-mail and change password" page then that would be better as you are not then exposing either the users e-mail address or password (even if it is auto-generated) via a plain text e-mail.

Comment: What you also need to consider is the value of what you are providing to the user. If they want it bad enough, they will be willing to fill in more information and won't abandon as easily and will lock into the process.

Comment: @Captain - that was partly the point of my 2nd paragraph.

Comment: I agree. Also, in case the user needs to enter a username, it could be good to just show that input first. When the username is confirmed as free, you could display a message "Congratulations! That name is free!", and then reveal email and password fields. That means they have made progress on the process of signing up and are less likely to give up.

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate ux is to require nothing :)

Ask yourself if your product or service actually requires a password. Is an email address enough on it's own? Does the data you capture with the email address need to be password protected?

Could you send the user a confirmation email and only ever require a password from them when it's necessary? When it is, ask them for one at the point. A password is minimal effort if the perceived reward is high.

In any case, a generated password will always be a design fail. I've seen enough numbers in my time to know that you'll have users hitting that forgotten password link 80% of the time. Leave the user to enter their own password, don't even generate one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends entirely on the context of the website, if for example you were building an e-commerce system and you wanted to streamline the sign up process so you can start building up analytics on that user as quickly as possible from a variety of cross platform devices that they access then an email address would suffice with a auto generated password.

Remember at this stage the user has no personal details stored within their account, they have only entered in their email address, and perhaps a name?  The auto generated password / email would then force the user upon next sign in to change their password, you can hardcode the password into the link itself.

No information at this point could be considered to be 'dangerous' if it got into the wrong hands, and at this point the user is changing the password to one they feel safe and secure with.

**However** if at the sign in screen you are taking address, phone number, card details then auto-generating a password would un-secure and pointless, the user has already entered in a myriad of data, what would one / two extra fields be?

Would auto generated passwords work for banking, car loans or other financial services? No, for websites / accounts that have no personal information that could be used, yes.

Answer (score 0):

100% good idea. You may leave only one email field or add some not required fields (when user in a good mood, he likely to fill some extra data)

Comment: Any constructive criticism?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to leave a comment. I thought as an answer that this was very poor. It's merely a short draft of your own opinion, with no reasoning what so ever. Own opinions without any factual evidence/reasoning to strengthen your case should exclusively be posted as comments, not answers. "100% good idea" is a very poor answer. That was why I voted this down.

Comment: Ok, i'll note that for future answers, thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that in general the minimum should be email address *and* some kind of username. You generally wouldn't want to expose user's email address in forum posts, comments, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is good, as user will not need to remember the login. He or she ends up with the login already well known to him/her.

Two watchouts regarding sending password to the registered email:
* it should be temporary (like: 10 minutes, for completing the registration)
* or even better, you should just provide a link in the email to go to a page where user can set the password. You will need to provide activation link anyway, so perhaps this is the best situation.

Of course everything depends on the system, in some situations it may be necessary to provide additional data.