# What happens when users register?

Tags: registration, signup-signon, patterns

Usually when users register on a site does the email confirmation contain their username and password? When the user clicks the activation link does it make the user sign in or deep link them into a page without signing in?

Comment: Related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19751/should-we-send-both-username-and-password-after-registration

Comment: Are you asking what *does* happen, or what *should* happen?

Answer (score 3):

A confirmation email of some sort is a must, I think.

About the auto login, I've always found having to login after activating an account a bit annoying. I'm not sure if this common practise helps reinforcing the user and pass association or it's easier because the system doesn't have to store this info. But when I sign up to a service it's usually because I need to use it immediately, so adding an extra step in that process always seemed unnecessary. There might be a technical reason behind it that I'm not aware of, though.

Comment: It's an added security against e-mail compromise (as e-mail is generally regarded an open communication network, that is, a lot of people are expected to be able to read your e-mail) so that noone can impersonate you even with your freshly created user. Even then this could be technically solved either with a "half-baked" session which turns into a full one when activating through the link or with a login form pre-filled with your username,with focus on password field.

Comment: @Aadaam thanks, I had no idea how it worked. Very interesting!

Comment: One problem with auto-login is if the site has a "remember me" checkbox, you can't choose to tick it.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Maybe it could use something like a lightbox to ask you if you want to save your pass when you are automatically logged in for the first time

Answer (score 1):

Usernames are sent very often, but not necessarily. If a user was asked to put in his *name*, then, most probably, in the email it will say "Hello [name]," etc. However, passwords should **never** be sent via email, for security reasons. Activation links often just link to a page where there is a confirmation message and sometimes they don't even show you any confirmation and just load the home page, but without logging in the user. In some rare cases, I've seen that the activation link also logs in the user.

Answer (score 1):

This is a process that I've given some thought to lately.

As to confirmation emails, those are almost expected nowadays. The username can be reiterated as part of the greeting, as in "Hello <username>". It is a bad idea to email the password to the user, it introduces security and trust concerns as to if the password is stored and communicated over cleartext.

Regarding the automatic login issue, a reasonable compromise could be the following flow:

1. When the user visits the site, signed-in or otherwise, start a short-lived session with the browser.
2. When the sign-up is completed, email them the verification link, tie this link to the session.
3. If the user clicks the link and the session is still active within their browser, there is no need to require them to log in again. They are on the same machine they completed the sign up on and are verifying within a reasonable amount of time.
4. If the session is not active, either is has expired or the user has changed machines, force them to log in.
5. Either way, deactivate the verification link after the account has been verified.

A large portion of users are likely to complete a sign-up in a single sitting, clicking the verification link as it is received. This method removes the annoying login step from the common case. At the same time, it doesn't make it possible for someone to intercept the link, and hijack the account.

Answer (score 0):

I'd disagree slightly with what folk are saying here.

Security hat on.

E-mailing a plain text password isn't a security faux pas because of the e-mail.

It's a security faux pas because it means that you are storing the password in plain text on the server. This, in turn, means that any server-side security failure giving attackers access to the password database means *everybody's* password is at risk.

If email was a useful attack vector for individuals then nobody would do password resets via email (since if an attacker can read your password in an email, they could also get at your password reset URL - and pwn you that way).

So - you shouldn't do it because you shouldn't be *able* to do it. Not because emailing passwords are a major problem themselves.

(It is a minor risk - since email is more vulnerable to attack that some other kinds of communication. But if you trust email enough to do password resets - you are saying that anybody with access to that email can get control of the account. This is why you will see sites that have real security implications doing offline password resets, or password resets via on-line security questions, or using two factor authentication of some kind, etc.).

Ok - security hat off. UX hat on.

Some things to think about:

- Some people don't have email. Or don't want to reveal their email.
- You cannot use the email without double checking that it actually belongs to the person registering. So validation of some kind is necessary.
- The person registering may be in a position where they cannot access their email immediately - or be in an environment where email delivery is slow. So forcing them to confirm email before they can continue may prevent some people from continuing - in some contexts that may mean they abandon the registration process.
- Some sites have a pattern of letting folk log in and having a separate e-mail validation phase. You can still use the account - you just can't get any e-mail related features until the email is validated (I think this site falls into that category).
- Whether you allow the activation link to log you in or not depends on the site and the security risk of letting this happen. However, if you are letting folk reset their password via email then having an automatic login link on email validation doesn't make things fundamentally more insecure (since both mean that people with access to the email account have access to the system account).

TL;DR - it depends ;-)